# DLL uses sqlite3 to write to same database file from different processes

Tags: c++, dll, sqlite

I am currently writting a .dll that uses sqlite3 to talk to a database on a windows system.

Right now, it is very simple and I have just written a test program that does inserts and selects from the database.

This issue however, is that my dll will be used by multiple programs on the same system, each writing to the same database file. This of course brings mutex issues with it.

I want to know the extent of which the sqlite3 library supports this before I go ahead and write a complicated connection pool for it. According to the doco there are things like "Shared Caches" and "No Mutex" Modes as specified by a paramater given to the `sqlite3_open_v2` function: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

I have also hunted around for a few sqlite3 wrappers but I cannot find anything that suits my multi-access needs.

Does anyone have any experience with writing to sqlite3 db files from multiple processes that use the same .dll? Or has anyone had any luck with using their `SHARED_CACHES` - I seem to run into all sorts of issues.

Any help on the matter would be great, thanks!

~ Dan

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're accessing the same database file through SQLite3, it should be fine. Indeed, SQLite3 is designed specifically to handle multiple processes accessing the same DB file.

SQL, as a specification, already deals with multiple accesses, and it provides controls for atomic accessing and so forth (transactions, that sort of thing). As long as you properly use those controls, you should be file.

It's multiple *threads* that SQLite3 has an issue with.

Comment: Thats for the help. I thought that was the case but I am getting issues that say database is already opened. Do I need top open and close my connection upon each query so that another process can have a change to use it in the interum?